# Replace colors in SASS using regex in php

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

## Problem

What i want to be able to do here is open a SASS variables file and then while preserving the formatting replace everything between the colon and semicolon where it is prepended with a particular selector string in php, the prepended bit needs to change according to a php variable. i do seem to be able to work out some regex that matches the string on [RegExr](http://regexr.com/),`/\primary-color:(.*?)\;` but when trying to use it in a `str_replace` it didnt work, added to this i also need to replace the primary-color selector with a php variable passed into the regex.

## File Contents

```php
string(328) "// 1. Colors $primary-color: #00c853; $link-color: #ff9800; $secondary-color: #ef6c00; $success-color: green; $error-color: red; $info-color: blue; $warning-color: orange; // 6. Chips $chip-bg-color: #e4e4e4 !default; $chip-border-color: #9e9e9e !default; $chip-selected-color: #26a69a !default; $chip-margin: 5px !default; "
```

## PHP Function

```php
/**
 * Set Sass Variables
 *
 * @param array $options contains the list of colors to use in the SASS
 */
public function set_sass_color($option = array()){
  $option['str'] = 'Example Text';
  $option_name = 'primary-color';
  $search = "/\primary-color:(.*?)\;/";
  $variables = file_get_contents(get_template_directory().'/assets/styles/common/_variables.scss');
  $variables_after = str_replace($search,$option['str'],$variables);
  return $variables_after;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

after some more searching i came across [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/), which gave me a better tool for working out the regex, i changed the `str_replace` to `preg_replace` and everything now seems to work as expected.

## PHP Function

```js
/**
 * Set Sass Variables
 *
 * @param array $option contains the option object for modifying the SASS
 */
public function set_sass_color($option = array()){
  $option['str'] = 'here';
  $option_name = 'primary-color';
  $search = '/('.$option_name.')[:](.*?)[;]/';
  $variables = file_get_contents(get_template_directory().'/assets/styles/common/_variables.scss');
  $variables_after = preg_replace($search,$option['str'],$variables);
  return $variables_after;
}
```